# How to write a JSTL instead of Scriplets to get the user Session?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Following:

```
<% if ((String) session.getAttribute("userID") != null) { 
     String username= (String) session.getAttribute("userID"); %> 
     <li><a><small>Logged in as <%=username %></a></li> 
<% } %>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: Here is the example of how to get [session information using JSTL](http://www.coderanch.com/t/525266/JSP/java/session-value-JSP-page-JSTL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should work:

```
<c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.userID}">
  <li><a><small>Logged in as ${sessionScope.userID}</a></li>
</c:if>
```